# I've rewritten someone else's old, closed question and nominated it for reopening, is that OK?

Tags: discussion, reopen-closed

It was obvious why this question was closed:
[What were Argentina's intentions for the Falkland Islanders?](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/8778/what-were-argentinas-intentions-for-the-falkland-islanders) (original title: **How does Argentina view the inhabitants of the Falklands?**)

But I figured it could be improved by turning it into a very similar (and properly historical, and on-topic) question. So I've had a go.

Recently we've been encouraged to improve and "reopen" closed questions so it seemed like something to try.

Is it OK to do so?

Comment: A better question now in my humble opinion, but is the change not so great that you should have posted it as a new question?

Comment: happy to go down that route

Comment: especially if the original poster says so. on the other hand he may be happy that it's faithful to his original enquiry

Comment: also, what is this reopening mechanism for, if not to allow for questions to be substantially reworked? after all, a minor edit isn't going to win 5 reopen votes

Comment: I agree that the original poster, if they are still around, will be the one to decide whether or not to accept your edits. Until now, I had thought of "reopen" as a feature useful to people who want to appeal closure of their question (with or without substantial rework), but you are right, anyone can edit a question and anyone can start a "reopen" vote.

Comment: I think it's the polite thing to ask the OP whether they are ok with the edit or prefer the edit to be a standalone question. If they reply, follow their decision. If they do not reply within a reasonable amount of time, then do whatever you think is better.