# Edit this closed question, or ask anew?

Tags: discussion, reopen-closed

This question, [Why was there no solution found to Soviet famines and near-famines?](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/16639/why-was-there-no-solution-found-to-soviet-famines-and-near-famines) was closed for beeing on social science. I think there's a valid and good question in there and that I could provide a good *historical* answer. The question, as I would put it, is "What did the SU do agains the famines, when, and why did millions still die?" which is actually answerable.
So my options are  a) Pose the question as a new one, with my own wording, and answer it myself or b) Edit the question and ask to reopen.

Problem with a) someone might come along and and say "hey, duplicate! VTC!"
Problem with b) The original question starts with the statement that the Holodomor was intentionally engineered which I believe to be false and which I would edit out. This would be a substantial edit to someone elses question, around an issue I and the asker disagree with. No matter who is right, asking the OP to approve my edit would probably be pointless (That's why I think [this discussion](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/634/ive-rewritten-someone-elses-old-closed-question-and-nominated-it-for-reopenin) is not really helpful).

So which way to reask the question is most likely to work (== not beeing closed or rejected), and attract even better answers than what I can provide?

Answer (score 3):

**Ask a separate question.**

"Why was there no solution" is a substantially different question to "What did they actually do". I for one would not consider them duplicates. The former has strong social science overtones about why the Soviet Union's agriculture was so poor despite being supposedly a technological power house. The latter is very much a actual inquiry into what measures the Soviets took to prevent famines.

However, I would caution not making the question too broad; i.e., ask what measures were taken after a specific famine. Not what did the USSR did for 70 years.

Comment: I'd also add that the existing question already has an accepted answer, so I don't know that reopening it is likely to change the accepted answer, even if more are added. However, it could make one of the (several) highly-voted answers already there no longer make sense.